# Could not convert from '<brace-enclosed initializer list> to

Tags: c++, c++11, std, stdmap

I know that has a lot of questions similar, but I saw them and none of them helped me, I think is that because mine is kind of different, and at the same time weird.

I made another question and a member answered to me, but instead of using classes he used structs. and it's working perfectly, but when I try to put it as classes, using the same logic, this is what happen, the error:

> error: could not convert '{{"foo", "bar"}}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'B'

I tried, but I don't know what is happening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(const std::string & input) : data(input) {}
private:
    std::string data;
};

class B
{
public:
    B();
    B(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string, A>> input) : container(begin(input), end(input)) {}
private:
    std::map<std::string, A> container;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    B b = {
        {"foo", "bar"}
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Also the answer of the member here: [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SeEmVl)

Thank you all.

Comment: A string literal to an `A` is two user-defined conversions, so that's not going to work implicitly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just tried this removing the "bar" and putting std::string("bar") and it worked. Do you have a solution to this work in both ways?

Comment: You could make an overload of `A`'s constructor that takes a `const char *` and delegates to the other one.

Comment: The only difference between `struct` and `class` is default access: `public` versus `private`.  (In fact, the only time I ever use the `class` keyword anymore is with template-template parameters.)  Do you mean aggregate versus non-aggregate?

Comment: I prefer to use classes sometimes because of the encapsulation, and it's a thing that I REALLY care about. Nut there are situations that you can use for sure the structs without concern.

Comment: You can get the same encapsulation with `struct` you can with `class`.  If the first thing you're going to do is put `public:` at the top, there's not really any effective difference.

Answer (score 3):

You must initialize the 'b' like this:

```
B b = {
    { "foo", A{"bar"} }
};
```

Because {"foo", "bar"} is of type {string, string} instead of {string, A}