# C++ default brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initialization

Let's say I have `c_student` class with several members and no constructors:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <typeinfo>

class c_student{
    // private:
    public:
        std::string name = "John";
        int         mark = 5;
        std::string second_name="Doe";

        void print(){
            std::cout << name <<" " << second_name << " : "<< mark<<"\n";
        }
    };

int main(){
    c_student stud_c  = {"Luke ",420};
    stud_c.print();
    c_student stud_d  = {"Mark "};
    stud_d.print();
        
}
```

This code works fine, but let's say I want to define custom constructors inside the class:

```cpp
        c_student (std::string n):name(n){};
        c_student() = default;
```

If I add them to class, the compiler complains that:

```
47_object_initialization.cpp:32:34: error: could not convert ‘{"Luke ", 420}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘c_student’
   32 |  c_student stud_c  = {"Luke ",420};
      |                                  ^
      |                                  |
      |                                  <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

I want to keep using default constructor for {} and so need to write something like:

```cpp
c_student( std::initializer_list <???>) = default; << Pseudo-code only!
```

But can't get how exactly. Could anyone points my attention on the right page of CPP reference?

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately not possible. The reason your code originally worked is due to [Aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). As soon as you created a user-defined constructor, your class is no longer an aggregate type

> An aggregate is one of the following types:
>
> - class type that has
>   -- no user-declared constructors

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe it is only possible in later standards, but there is some related info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21941967/could-not-convert-from-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-to

Comment: @SvenNilsson The reason that code works is they provided a user-defined constructor for `B`, which the OP is free to do here as well. However the OP here wants to "bring back" the `default` aggregate initialization behavior, which as the standard mentions is not possible. They would have to define a user-defined constructor to emulate that kind of behavior, which undermines the `default` compiler generated behavior.

Comment: Ok, I understand. You are right but there is a workaround...

Answer (score 2):

You can use brace-initialization to achieve what you want by replacing all the constructors with the following one:

```
c_student (std::string name = "John", int mark = 5, std::string second_name = "Doe") 
  : name(name), mark(mark), second_name(second_name) {};
```

Also, you can remove the default member initializers since the only way to construct a `c_student` will give them the default values if they are not provided.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vG1aqj).

Comment: Nice and efficient. However, what if the order of list elements is different, like `{"First", "Last", 20}` ?

Comment: @AdrianMole Without C++20 designated initializers, there's no way to muck around with the order of parameters.

Comment: You can provide explicit (and separate) constructors with different argument orders.

Comment: @AdrianMole Sometimes, but I think all arguments would need to be different types. e.g. how would you disambiguate between `c_student("Adrian")`? Is that the first, or second name? Hmm, actually UDL would work be a fix for that, but it's a lot of work just for different constructor orders.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another user-defined constructor to handle the initializer list with two entries (and keep adding such constructors for each possible list size and order). The following compiles and works as expected:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class c_student {
private:
    std::string name = "John";
    int         mark = 5;
    std::string second_name = "Doe";
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << name << " " << second_name << " : " << mark << "\n";
    }
    c_student(std::string n) : name(n) { }  // Called for initializer list {"xxx"}
    c_student(std::string n, int m) : name(n), mark(m) { } // Called for list {"xxx", m}
    c_student(std::string n, std::string s, int m) : name(n), mark(m), second_name(s) { } // Called for list {"xxx", "yyy", m}
    c_student() = default;
};

int main()
{
    c_student stud_c = { "Luke", 420 };
    stud_c.print();
    c_student stud_d = { "Mark" };
    stud_d.print();
    c_student stud_e = { "John", "Smith", 333 };
    stud_e.print();
    return 0;
}
```